# How can I use a SELECT statement as a table in the FROM statement in another query?

Tags: sql

I have two queries:

1. A query that selects the population and loads it into a table.
2. A query that uses this table as one of its sources in the FROM statement.

How can I use the first query as a source without loading it into a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below

```
select (A query that uses this table as one of its sources in the FROM statement) 
from (
A query that selects the population and loads it into a table) xxx
```

Example:

```
select * from (
select col1, col2, ...., coln
from some_table) xxx
```

Comment: The format I used was:
SelectStatementFromSecondQuery FROM (first query) xxx where ClausesFromSecondQuery